# Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function - Value undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

The error is around `getSourceURL` and being able to mock its response as it's called internally inside of a call from `logger`:

```
import { logger, getSourceURL } from '@server/utils/logger';

jest.mock('@server/utils/logger', () => ({
  getSourceURL: jest.fn()
}));

getSourceURL.mockReturnValue('https://localhost:3000/women')
```

`jest.js`

```
describe('Has Error Response', () => {
  it('Should log an error message', () => {
    expect(logger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      `Response Error - Time: NaNms - response status: ${status}`
    );
  });
});
```

`/utiles/logger`

```
const getSourceURL = (req, path = '') => {
  const protocol = getProtocol(req);
  const urlPath = path === '' && req && typeof req?.reqPath !== 'undefined' ? req?.reqPath : path;
  return printSourceURL(`${protocol}://${req.headers.host}${urlPath}`);
};
const logger = (message, severity = 'I') => {
  const output = `${getDateTime()} ${process.pid} ${severity} ${message}\n`;
  console.log(output);
};
const logAccess = (req, res, timeTaken) => {
  const output = 'something'
  logger(output, 'A');
  return output;
};
```

Jest error:

```
Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined
```

Comment: `logger` doesn't seem to be defined inside `jest.js`, so that error makes sense. Also the test seems to lack a "given" or "when", just a "then".